# issue with JPA many to many with extra column in join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I m trying to set a JPA mapping for a many-to-many relationship with an extra column in the join table. My model looks like this :
Hikelist (id), Item(id), ItemList(idList, itItem, quantity)

My mapping :

Item :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Collection<Itemlist> setOfItemHikelist = new ArrayList<Itemlist>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<Itemlist> getSetOfItemHikelist() {
        return setOfItemHikelist;
    }

    public void setSetOfItemHikelist(Collection<Itemlist> setOfItemHikelist) {
        this.setOfItemHikelist = setOfItemHikelist;
    }
}
```

ItemList:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ITEM_LIST")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.item", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "iditem")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.hikelist", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idlist")) })
public class Itemlist implements Serializable {

    private ItemListId pk = new ItemListId();

    @EmbeddedId
    public ItemListId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ItemListId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }   

    @Transient
    public Item getItem() {
        return getPk().getItem();
    }

    public void setStock(Item item) {
        getPk().setItem(item);
    }

    @Transient
    public Hikelist getHikelist() {
        return getPk().getHikelist();
    }

    public void setCategory(Hikelist hikelist) {
        getPk().setHikelist(hikelist);
    }

    private String quantity;

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    } 
}
```

ItemListId:

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemListId implements java.io.Serializable{

    private Item item;
    private Hikelist hikelist;

    @ManyToOne
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Hikelist getHikelist() {
        return hikelist;
    }
    public void setHikelist(Hikelist hikelist) {
        this.hikelist = hikelist;
    }
}
```

I m getting this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: java.util.Collection, at table: T_HIKELIST, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(setOfItemHikelist)]     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)     at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)

If someone can help me on this... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing AccesType , in the class Item you use the annotations in FIELDS and PROPERTIES, consider do this.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.item", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Itemlist> setOfItemHikelist = new ArrayList<Itemlist>();

public Collection<Itemlist> getSetOfItemHikelist() {
    return setOfItemHikelist;
}
```

Put the annotations over the fields as you did in the Id in the same class